# Ruby OpenSSL vs Linux openssl

Tags: ruby, openssl, aes, sha256

I have a difficulty reconciling Ruby's OpenSSL library with the standard Linux command line openssl.

What I'm trying to do here is encrypt the string **mysecretstring** with the password **foobar** but first hashing the password using sha256 (mimicking the code in the [aescrypt gem](https://github.com/Gurpartap/aescrypt/blob/master/lib/aescrypt.rb)).

Here is what I do in **IRB**:

```
2.0.0-p353 :041 > aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
 => #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x000000026b8d50> 
2.0.0-p353 :042 > aes.encrypt
 => #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x000000026b8d50> 
2.0.0-p353 :043 > aes.key=OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new('foobar').digest
 => "\xC3\xAB\x8F\xF17 \xE8\xAD\x90G\xDD9Fk<\x89t\xE5\x92\xC2\xFA8=J9`qL\xAE\xF0\xC4\xF2" 
2.0.0-p353 :044 > Base64.encode64(aes.update('mysecretstring')+aes.final)
 => "305V0Kbklj/HoBSK4ferhA==\n" 
2.0.0-p353 :045 >
```

So far so good. Now I want to see how this matches what I can do with openssl directly in the linux command line.

```
[(master)]$ echo -n "foobar" | openssl dgst -sha256 -c
(stdin)= c3:ab:8f:f1:37:20:e8:ad:90:47:dd:39:46:6b:3c:89:74:e5:92:c2:fa:38:3d:4a:39:60:71:4c:ae:f0:c4:f2
[(master)]$ echo -n "mysecretstring" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
U2FsdGVkX18EOcTrTMNQuCRnstUe6oY9b5RLuTOFcNo=
[(master)]$
```

where in the last two steps I pasted the string `c3:ab:8f:f1:37:20:e8:ad:90:47:dd:39:46:6b:3c:89:74:e5:92:c2:fa:38:3d:4a:39:60:71:4c:ae:f0:c4:f2` 
that I got by hashing the password 'foobar' in the first step.

Why am I not getting the same answer, and more importantly, what do I need to do in the linux cmd to mimic what I get from Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-K` option in your `openssl` line. Then you can provide the hexadecimal key. Otherwise OpenSSL uses it's own key derivation mechanism to derive a key from the password. When supplying `-K` you should also supply `-iv`. In this case, to be compatible, the IV should consist of 16 bytes set to zero.

So try the following line:

```
echo -n "mysecretstring" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -K c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks owlstead. I guess I'm still not getting it. How exactly do I specify the iv? I'm trying something like: echo -n "mysecretstring" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -K c3:ab:8f:f1:37:20:e8:ad:90:47:dd:39:46:6b:3c:89:74:e5:92:c2:fa:38:3d:4a:39:60:71:4c:ae:f0:c4:f2 -iv 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 but I get an error saying that the hex string is too long. When I shorten it it just becomes invalid hex iv value. I'd really appreciate further clarification. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of OpenSSL command line about the parameters?

Comment: You've managed to smuggle in some weird Unicode characters in the middle of your hex; they even were copied to the site :) Found out because the cursor kept hanging on them. This is probably due to the string returned by `digest`, better to print them as hex manually instead if you require the contents.